# Using FlowRouter SSR with meteor and get the connection info on server

Tags: meteor, nginx, flow-router

We are looking for a way to work with the connection information of a request. The main part we need is the domain - for an authentication.

This is How we do it currently (not exactly - but its easier to show it with this code snipped):

```
// Routes.jsx
FlowRouter.route('/my-route', {
  action(params) {
    params.auth = false;
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      params.auth = Meteor.call('authMethod');
    } else {
      Meteor.call('authMethod', (err, auth) => {
        FlowRouter.setParams({
          auth
        });
      });
    }
    mount(MyApp, params);
  }
});



// Methods.js - on Server only 
Meteor.methods({
  'authMethod'() {
    if (Meteor.isClient) return false;
    if (!this.connection) return false;
    return this.connection.host === 'my-allowed-domain.com';
  }
});
```

As you can see we check if this.connection is set in our method. This is because when the FlowRouter SSR will render the content on server this.connection is always set to `null`.

**What is working now ?:**

Only when the content is rendered on client it will work because the client will call the Meteor methods and send the connection object to it.

**What should it do ?:**

Also when the FlowRouter SSR will render the route on server we need the connection information!

**Solutions:**

We know that there is a Meteor.absoluteUrl method but this will always return the absolute server route - but we are working with nginx to use multi domains with one server so the Meteor.absoluteUrl in our case is always localhost:3000 on server.

We've saw that FlowRouter will add a ssrContext object to the FlowRouter Object on server only - but this object will just add the property slot - nothing else.

**So our question:**

Is there any way to get information about the connection when the route is rendered by FlowRouter SSR ? Of course we are not able to get the connection information when there is no real request from the client - but in the case of FlowRouter SSR there is a request by client and the FlowRouter will automatically render the route in 2 ways: client & server. So is there a way to get the information ?

**Update**

I've done a small package which is adding the req Object in the process of Picker. You can find it here:

https://github.com/TimoRuetten/meteor-flow-router-ssr-request

I have no idea if this was necessary so if you know a build in way to get this information it would be nice.